# OLEDB provider not registered

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, webforms, oledb

I have read many forums but still getting the error

> Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I am using windows 8.1 64bit and Visual Studio 2013 and using oledb connection. Here is my connection string.

("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0", path);

I also installed MS Access Database 32bit.

Now it works perfect on my local machine. but when I host my web application to the server then i am getting error. I also build and compile my application in x86 mode. And in my Application Pool setting. Enable 32bit mode is set to true. but still getting error. hosting server doesn't allow to install software like office, ms access database.

My connection string seems correct. Please Help!!

Comment: The ACE driver needs to be installed on your web server too. Not sure of the version, but [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255) is a link to the distributable.

Comment: Web server doesn't allow us to install external drivers..

Comment: Check out [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/403846/deploy-ms-access-driver-to-connect-in-asp-net-shared-hosting) SO item. I really don't think you can do it, the ACE drivers need to be registered, if you can't register them you can't use them. Looks like time to research db alternatives which your server can handle. Be interested to see the "answer" to this.

Comment: Web server owner suggest me to buy a dedicated server so that i can install drivers.. But it is too costly..